# Phantomjs and dynamic link libraries (dll)

Tags: dll, phantomjs

Can i connect to the function in dll from Phantomjs? Like this.

```
var driver = new ActiveXObject ("AddIn.FPrnM8");
```

This code work for ie. I want to get object DRIVER  from phantomjs.
FprnM1C.dll reg in OS with regsrv32.
Thanks.

Comment: How to access the function in dll file?

Comment: Slimerjs or Casperjs can do this?